# Get Album Genre with MediaStore

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm very new to how cursors work in Android. Currently, I am able to retrieve an album's name and artist, but I am not able to retrieve it's genre. I've looked around and cannot find a way to do this. Should I just check over all the songs in the album, find the most common genre and assign the album genre based on that, or is there a more elegant way to do this? Typically all songs in an album will have the same genre, but this is not always the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with [MediaMetaDataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)?

`MediaMetadataRetriever media = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
media.setDataSource("file.mp3");
media.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_GENRE);`

Comment: That would be for a song genre, not an album genre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MetaDataRetriever` if you want...It's (in my experience) a more complete way to retrieve metadata from a song (you can see more in the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html )...I wrote something like this in a project of mine, hope this can help you:

```
  public void MetSongRetriever() {

    //MediaPlayerPlay is the context, I shared a function i wrote myself
    //Just like myUri is the path of the song (external storage in my case)
    mMediaData.setDataSource(MediaPlayerPlay.this, myUri);

    try {

        mNameSong.setText(mMediaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
        mBandName.setText(mMediaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        mCoverImage.setImageBitmap(songImage);               

        mAlbumName.setText(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
        mGenre.setText(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE)); 

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

       //set all the text Uknown, like "Unknown title" and so on
       //And the background for the image grey
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Well, if I understood correctly, you want to show info like title, album, band, genre and so on of each songs in a list right?
I usually use a ListView for that...you can use ListView + creating a custom class to settle the info + an ArrayAdapter to inherit the class structure and show it in a ListView...maybe something like (just using title, band, album and the path where the song is stored, external storage in my case, you can add what you want following these lines)

**Songs.java**

```
public class Songs {

public String mSongname, mBandName, mAlbumName, mPathSong;


public Songs(String songName, String bandName, String albumName, String pathSong) {

    mSongname = songName;
    mBandName = bandName;
    mAlbumName = albumName;
    mPathSong = pathSong;

}


public void setSongname(String songname) {
    mSongname = songname;
}

public void setBandName(String bandName) {
    mBandName = bandName;
}

public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
    mAlbumName = albumName;
}

public void setPathSong(String pathSong) {
    mPathSong = pathSong;
}


public String getSongname() {

    return mSongname;
}

public String getBandName() {

    return mBandName;
}

public String getAlbumName() {

    return mAlbumName;
}

public String getPathSong() {

    return mPathSong;
}
```

**SongsAdapter.java**

```
public class SongsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Songs> {

public SongsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Songs> mySongs) {

    super(context, 0, mySongs);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Storing the data from the current position
    Songs mySongs = getItem(position);

    //Check if the convertview is reused, otherwise i load it
    if(convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_songs, parent, false);
    }

    //Filling the structure with data
    TextView SongTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_songs_title);
    TextView BandName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_songs_band);
    TextView AlbumName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_songs_album);
    TextView PathName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_songs_path);

    //Inserting the data in the template view
    SongTitle.setText(mySongs.mSongname);
    BandName.setText(mySongs.mBandName);
    AlbumName.setText(mySongs.mAlbumName);
    PathName.setText(mySongs.mPathSong);

    //Return of the view for visualisation purpose
    return convertView;
}
}
```

The following one is the function I used to retrieve the data (i used the index i just for storing all the songs' paths in a string array, to use them in another activity, not usefull for you)

```
    public void getMusicList() {

    int i = 0;

    //I used the content resolver to get access to another part of the device, in my case the external storage
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();

    //Taking the external storage general path
    Uri mSongUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    //The cursor is used to point to a certain row in the temp database, so you can store just parts of it and not the whole database (efficiency maxed)
         Cursor mSongCursor = getContentResolver().query(mSongUri, null, null, null, null, null);

    if ((mSongCursor != null) && mSongCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        //Gathering the index of each column for each info i want
        int mTempSongTitle = mSongCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int mTempBand = mSongCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int mTempAlbum = mSongCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int mTempLocationPath = mSongCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


        do {

            //Gathering the real info based on the index
            String mCurrentTitle = mSongCursor.getString(mTempSongTitle);
            String mCurrentBand = mSongCursor.getString(mTempBand);
            String mCurrentAlbum = mSongCursor.getString(mTempAlbum);
            String mCurrentPath = mSongCursor.getString(mTempLocationPath);

            mListOfPaths[i] = mCurrentPath;
            i++;

            Songs newSong = new Songs(mCurrentTitle, mCurrentBand, mCurrentAlbum, mCurrentPath);
            adapter.add(newSong);


        } while (mSongCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

And this last function is used to show finally all the data gathered in previous function

```
     public void doStuff() {

    mSongNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ID_MPM_listView);
    mSongNames.setAdapter(adapter);

    getMusicList();

    //The event it will occur when you click on an item of the listView

    mSongNames.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent mMediaPlayerPlayIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerMain.this, MediaPlayerPlay.class);

            mMediaPlayerPlayIntent.putExtra("ExtraPosition", position);
            mMediaPlayerPlayIntent.putExtra("StringArray", mListOfPaths);

            startActivity(mMediaPlayerPlayIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this now and see how I get on. I appreciate the detailed and well commented code snippet.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help! I appreaciate when someone tell me exatly what I want, so I tend to do the same! Let me know if this works :)

Comment: I did a bit of research on the MediaMetadataRetriever, and while it is useful and I may use it later on currently I don't think it solves my problem. I need to display album information in a list (specifically, a RecyclerView). Specifically, all albums on a user's device akin to Google Play Music. Is this possible with MediaMetadataRetriever, or is it only for individual albums/songs?

Comment: @Eamonn 
I edited my answer, I hope i understood well what you asked, and if it is correct, let me know if these info helped you out with you problem :)

Comment: This is how i see my listView (shitty pic, i know, i dont use the emulator)
https://unsee.cc/boretina/

Comment: Yup, this was pretty much what I was looking to do. Thanks!